# How to find all the posible combinations of 3 objects of with 2 properties that will sum to a total of 3 distinct properties

Tags: math, combinations, formula

I'm trying to figure out what is the mathematical formula that will represent the following situation:

1. I have X number of colors, and Y balls, each has 2 colors.
2. I calculate the Y amount of balls by:
   Y = X! / (X - 2)! * 2!

Now, my mission is to find the total amount of combinations of 3 balls that will be in the following form:

1. first and second ball has one color that is similar.
2. the second color of the first and second ball must not be the same.
3. the third ball has the colors of the 2 other balls (that is not shared between them)

I wrote a code that will help me simulate what I'm looking for, but was not able to reverse engineer it to the formula that will help me calculate the numeric result without simulating it.

**The code:**

```
var Colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'white' , 'black'];

C = Colors.length;
document.write("Balls: " + Colors.length + '<br>');
document.write(Colors.join() + '<br>');

BallsCount = (sFact(C) / (sFact(C-2) * 2));
document.write("BallsCount: " + BallsCount + '<br>');

var Balls = new Array();
for (i=0, c=1; i<Colors.length;i++)
  for (x=i+1; x<Colors.length; c++, x++)
  {
    document.write(c + ": " + Colors[i] + '/' + Colors[x] + '<br>');
    Balls[c-1] = Colors[i] + '/' + Colors[x];
  }

//Triangles = BallsCount / 3;
TrianglesCount = (sFact(BallsCount) / (sFact(BallsCount-3) * sFact(3)));
document.write("Triangles: " + TrianglesCount + '<br>');

var Triangles = new Array();
for (i=0, c=1; i<Balls.length;i++)
  for (y=i+1; y<Balls.length; y++)
    for (x=y+1; x<Balls.length; x++)
    {
      if (Balls[i].split('/')[0] == Balls[y].split('/')[0] && ( Balls[i].split('/')[1] + '/' + Balls[y].split('/')[1] == Balls[x] || Balls[y].split('/')[1] + '/' + Balls[i].split('/')[1] == Balls[x]))
      {
        document.write(c + ": " + Balls[i] + " - " + Balls[y] + " - " + Balls[x] + '<br>');
        Triangles[c] = Balls[i] + " - " + Balls[y] + " - " + Balls[x];
        c++;
      }
    }

function sFact(num)
{
    var rval=1;
    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++)
        rval = rval * i;
    return rval;
}
```

the results:

```
Colors: 6

red,blue,green,yellow,white,black

Balls: 15

1. red/blue
2. red/green
3. red/yellow
4. red/white
5. red/black
6. blue/green
7. blue/yellow
8. blue/white
9. blue/black
10. green/yellow
11. green/white
12. green/black
13. yellow/white
14. yellow/black
15. white/black

Triangles:

1. red/blue - red/green - blue/green
2. red/blue - red/yellow - blue/yellow
3. red/blue - red/white - blue/white
4. red/blue - red/black - blue/black
5. red/green - red/yellow - green/yellow
6. red/green - red/white - green/white
7. red/green - red/black - green/black
8. red/yellow - red/white - yellow/white
9. red/yellow - red/black - yellow/black
10. red/white - red/black - white/black
11. blue/green - blue/yellow - green/yellow
12. blue/green - blue/white - green/white
13. blue/green - blue/black - green/black
14. blue/yellow - blue/white - yellow/white
15. blue/yellow - blue/black - yellow/black
16. blue/white - blue/black - white/black
17. green/yellow - green/white - yellow/white
18. green/yellow - green/black - yellow/black
19. green/white - green/black - white/black
20. yellow/white - yellow/black - white/black
```

What would be the formula to calculate the total amount of combinations ?

Another question is, if for example, Alice has a set of balls as described above, and Bob has a set of similar balls with some colors that Alice has and some that she don't (and vice versa), so for N number of participants how could I calculate the maximum amount of combination of 3 that comes from all the participants together? (more than 1 ball per participant is allowed)

Thanks.

Comment: Total amount of triangles is number of triples of colors = X! / (3! * (X-3)!)

Answer (score 1):

As Egor says: X!/[(X-r)!(r!)]
Where order is unimportant and repetition is not allowed. The case for the "triangles" is with r=3, 6!/(3!3!)=20